# What is the meaning of the poem line given below by Seamus Heaney ? I tried understanding it but could not. Please help

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> *History says*,
>
> *Don’t hope on this side of the grave*,
>
> *But then, once in a lifetime*
>
> *The longed-for tidal wave*
>
> *Of justice can rise up,*
>
> *And hope and history rhyme.*

Comment: Which line? You quoted six lines.

Comment: I couldn't get the essence of the whole part mentioned there. Can you please make me understand @MichaelHarvey please if its possible for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> History says,
> Don’t hope on this side of the grave

This means that history is full of misery and dashed hopes, and that might make a person pessimistic about the future. 'History' is personified in this poem, 'telling' people not to hope. "This side of the grave" refers to life.

> But then, once in a lifetime
> The longed-for tidal wave
> Of justice can rise up

This gives the reader reason for hope - that sometimes (once in a lifetime) justice does happen.

> And hope and history rhyme.

This means that, when something good and just happens, it makes new history that *does* give reason for hope.